# How to fetch values from given xpath? working for one field not with other field

Tags: javascript, xpath, element, playwright

from this text field I want values, when I do inspect xpath shows result.
[image]
But when I run the playwright code, it shows NULL value. Have tried "getattribute" as well as "gettextcontent" but works for other fields.

[image]

Comment: Please post code as [text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code behind `this.iGetTextContent()` and the locator for `ID_Overridepage` please?

Comment: @AJG this is the code behind  this.iGetTextContent() method is 'protected iGetTextContent(selector: string) { return this.page.textContent(selector) } ' The locator I have used for 'ID_Overridepage' is '//input[@id="ID"]'

Comment: Couldn't post what I wanted you to try in a comment, so added as an answer for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
import { expect, Page } from '@playwright/test';

test('Trying stuff out', async ({ page }) => {
  await expect(page.locator(MyproSelectors.ID_Overridepage)).toHaveValue('your-expected-value-here')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> For text fields ,in any automation framework/library always use
> "value" property compared to textcontent or other properties for reliable results.

For [playwright](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator) , I would use the below syntax for fetching text value:

```
await page.locator('inputLocator').inputValue();
```

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-input-value